# Rails Tutorial: Why can I sign up a new user without problems on the local server but not on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've completed the Rails Tutorial. I kept up with every detail until the end of chapter 8. The last four chapters I just copied and pasted without trying to understand much.

The Sample App works perfectly on a Cloud9 local web server, but not on Heroku. Specifically, When I want to sign up a new user, I get the message "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Why can I sign up a new user without problems on the local server but not on Heroku? Is the functionality of the final sample app supposed to be exactly the same on both local and heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completed every step in the entire Rails Tutorial book, except one, which I thought was optional and wouldn't affect the result in production.

10.3 Email in Production shows you how to configure your application to send emails in production (for account activation in the book's sample application) using a Heroku add-on called Sendgrid.

You do have to give Heroku credit card information (though for the purposes of the book you don't have to actually make any purchase or subscription), and this is why I initially didn't implement this section of the book.

After following along and implementing section 10.3 my final application is fully functional in production.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 500, look at the server logs for a clue. Probably need to run migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Run your migrations:

```
heroku run rake:db migrate
```

You may need to restart heroku:

```
heroku restart
```

If it still doesn't work, try resetting your database. If you're using postgres, try:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```